# How do I use modular arithmetic on indices?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to create a function that, for each member of a list, returns the value of that member and the number of values either side of it. The only trick is that it has to "wrap around" when it is at the start or end of the list

For example:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  
myfunc(a,2) # 2 indicates 2 either side

[8,9,0,1,2]
[9,0,1,2,3]
[0,1,2,3,4]
...
...
[6,7,8,9,0]
[7,8,9,0,1]
```

I can work out how to do it from index 2 until 7:

```
def myfunc(vals, rnge):
    for i in range(0+rnge, len(vals)-rnge):
        print vals[i-rnge:i+rnge+1]
```

But I can't work out how to handle when it needs to wrap around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
def defunc(vals, start, rnge):
    n = len(vals)
    new = []

    for i in xrange((start - rnge), (start + rnge)+ 1):
        new.append(vals[i%n])
    return new

def myfunc(vals, rnge):
    n = len(vals)
    for i in range(n):
        print defunc(vals,i,rnge)
```

I am not slicing the list to make the logic clearer.
I hope this works

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i need! this way i can avoid duplicating my list

Comment: This is making a new list len(vals) * 2 * range times.  It is a lot of operations.

Comment: yes, but while i probably won't use the whole piece of code, i can use the loop that is in defunc() to make a list of indexes that i can return to the original function..

Comment: @guskenny83 yeah ! I didnt want to give you the copy-paste code. Now you have to do some work ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

you could  try this (extend `vals` in both directions first). there may be something in `collections` that allows for this to be done more efficiently:

```
def myfunc(vals, rnge):
    vals_ext = vals[-rnge:] + vals + vals[:rnge]
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        print( vals_ext[i:i+2*rnge+1] )
```

output:

```
[8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
[9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate your lists using the numpy element-wise modulo of an (unshifted) array.

You want 5 elements that wrap around 10, so use modulo 10. For example if the list starts with 8:

```
np.mod(np.arange(8,8+5,1),10)  returns [8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
```

To get all 10 possible lists, evaluate `list(np.mod(np.arange(s,s+5,1),10))`for each start `s=1,2,..,10`

Or, in a single list comprehension without resorting to numpy,

```
[[t%10 for t in range(s,s+5)] for s in range(10)]
```

returns

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
 [7, 8, 9, 0, 1],
 [8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
 [9, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def myfunc(vals, rnge):
    valsX3 = vals*3;
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        print valsX3[i:i+2*rnge+1]
```

You could use something like this to avoid the duplication of arrays:
[wrapping around slices in Python / numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739543/wrapping-around-slices-in-python-numpy)

Not sure how it does it internally though.

Comment: this is similar to the above answer where you extend the list on either side.. is there no way of calculating the indexes? if i have very long arrays of values, or if the lists contain very large and complex objects, then i would imagine doing it this way would be very inefficient..

Comment: You could do it as separate operations.  Or use this:

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach you might also find useful:

```
def myfunc(alist, offset):
    adeque = collections.deque(a)       
    adeque.rotate(offset)
    for i in xrange(len(alist)):
        print list(itertools.islice(adeque, 0, 2*offset+1))
        adeque.rotate(-1)

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  
myfunc(a,2) # 2 indicates 2 either side
```

It makes use of the `deque` collections object which has an efficient `rotate` function.